# Getting around the message: Informational: The full-text search condition contained noise word(s)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using the Full Text Search in SQLServer 2008 R2 to speed up query processing that currently uses the LIKE '%searchTerm%'.

I have a search page (ASP .Net) that passes values for the various searchable fields, and calls a stored proc that is executed by the Entity Framework 4.5.

The issue is that SQLServer generates an information message whenever you use the full text search functions (freetext, contains, etc.) with empty predicates.

Is there a way to have entity framework ignore the informational message and get the results?

This seems to be a common problem with Full Text Search, and I haven't found a way to turn it off.

The scenario is a basic address table:

```
    CREATE TABLE [Address](
    [AddressID] [int] IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
    [HouseNumber] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [AddressLine1] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [AddressLine2] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [StateCode] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [ZipCode] [char](10) NULL,
    [ApartmentNumber] [varchar](8) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_NewBuilding] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    [AddressID] ASC )
```

The table has a full text index on it

```
    CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Address
(
    HouseNumber                      
        Language 1033,            
    AddressLine1
        Language 1033,
    AddressLine2
        Language 1033,
    City
        Language 1033,
    ZipCode
        Language 1033
)
KEY INDEX PK_NewBuilding ON AddressSearchCatalog
WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO
```

The following sample query works fine, but returns the Informational Message due to some of the search terms being empty.  The real query is fairly complex, crossing multiple tables, and would be a nightmare to build a Dynamic SQL query.

```
    declare @pBuildingHouseNumber nvarchar(8) = N'""', 
    @pStreet nvarchar(30) = N'"Williams"',
    @pCity nvarchar(20)= N'""',
    @pZipCode nchar(10) = N'""'

select HouseNumber,AddressLine2,City,StateCode,ZipCode
from Building 
where 
    (@pBuildingHouseNumber = '""' OR CONTAINS(HouseNumber, @pBuildingHouseNumber) ) and
    (@pStreet = '""' OR FREETEXT((AddressLine2,AddressLine1), @pStreet) ) and
    (@pCity = '""' OR CONTAINS(City, @pCity) ) and
    (@pZipCode = '""' OR CONTAINS(ZipCode, @pZipCode) ) 
    option (recompile)
```

Looking at the Messages Window in SSMS, I Get

```
Informational: The full-text search condition contained noise word(s).

(49 row(s) affected)
```

But the Result Set does come back in SSMS.  In Entity Framework, it throws an Error.

Has anyone gotten around this problem?

I have tried to turn off the Stop List

> ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON Address SET STOPLIST = OFF

I have tried turning on the transform noise word option

> sp_configure 'transform noise words', 1;
>
> RECONFIGURE;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after a few days of searching, I wasn't able to find a way to turn this message off.

I did however fix the issue with Entity Framework, in that it was an error in the stored procedure regarding how it was called.

When testing from SSMS, we would call the proc similarly to the parameters above.

The stored procedures had default values for parameters that were not passed.

So when using defaults, those defaults only get applied when you don't pass a value for that paramter.  When you execute the stored proc and pass an explicit null for that parameter, it doesn't take the default and the null was being passed to the full text search, which correctly throws an error.

Another one of those DOH I forgot moment.